# How to resize a VirtualBox HDD image

Tags: filesystems, virtualbox, storage

I initially created a dynamically expanding VirtualBox image, and have tried to increase its hard drive space:

```
VBoxManage modifyhd "VirtualBox VMs/JHBuild/JHBuild.vdi" --resize 16384
```

After that, I saw from the UI that it has increased to 16GB logical size:

[image]

Sadly, when I boot the image, I still get the initial size (e.g. when I use `df`).

Answer (score 5):

You should realize that when you boot a virtual machine, it sees the virtual disk as  if it was a physical device and, as I understand from your description, the system you boot **resides** on the disk. So look from the point of view of your normal system: You've got a bigger disk but have the old-sized partition on it. Certainly, you must resize it. But **not** after booting into that very system (that is, not from *the disk*) - just as you should never resize your partition, from which your system booted.

So the solution is to download a bootable CD iso image like [SystemRescueCD](http://www.sysresccd.org/) or [Gparted live](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php). Add it to your virtual machine (just in the menu you showed in your picture - select the "SATA Controller", click "Add CD/DVD Device" icon and then, on the right, browse for your iso file) and set to boot from that instead of the disk image (but do not remove the image of course). Once you've booted, run `gparted` and resize the partition. Shutdown the machine, remove the iso from it and boot back to your virtual disk :)

Comment: I don't see why it makes a difference if you booted from this disk or not. In both cases, you should have a backup. If you then remove and re-establish the needed partition, reboot and do a online `resize2fs`, all should be ok.

Comment: Absolutely not. Can you cut and enlarge a boat while floating on it? Or change the suspension while driving a car? This is shooting at your own knees. The system *is running* from the partition you are trying to change!

Comment: BTDT. Several times. You as well? A changed (removed and re-established) partition won't be recognized by the running OS - it behaves as if the partition table was the old one. This is safe until the next reboot, where the new size is recognized - but not yet by the file system. And the, now pending, online resizing of FS has been existing for years with no problems.

Answer (score 3):

After increasing the size of the underlying device, you must as well increase the size of the file system and, if so, everything in-between (partitions, LVM stuff etc.).

If you don't have any if them, and your file system is ext[23], you can just use

```
resize2fs /dev/...
```

in order to increase up to the auto-determined size.

Comment: Running `sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1` gives me `The filesystem is already 2096640 blocks long.  Nothing to do!`.

Comment: Running `sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1 16G` gives me `The containing partition (or device) is only 2096640 (4k) blocks\nYou requested a new size of 4194304 blocks.`.

Comment: Seems like the partition is too small, as only the size of the underlying blockdevice (`/dev/sda`) has changed. So you have to change the size of the partition first. Use `cfdisk`, `fdisk` or `sfdisk` and note the parameters of your partition, remove it and add it again at the same position but with a higher size. Then you should be able to `resize2fs` the file system.

Answer (score 3):

*WARNING:  e2fsck will likely harm a mounted partition*

You've just modified your disk (partition) size; You'll need to do the following to modify you fs size (providing that you are using ext* fs:

```
e2fsck -f /dev/<partition>
resize2fs /dev/<partition> <size>
```

HTH